# Получить индекс коллекции при нажатии + AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Хочу получить индекс элемента из таблицы и потом манипулировать им. Сам индекс получаю, но блок AJAX его не видит.

```
    <table border="1" >
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>ID R</th><th>ID U</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id='trash'>
           <tr>
               <td data-label='ID R'>$row[0]</td>
               <td data-label='ID U'>$row[1]</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

---

```
   $("table").on('click', function(event){
        var table = document.querySelectorAll('tr') || [];
        table = [].slice.apply(table);

        event.preventDefault();
        table.forEach(function (element, i) {
            element.addEventListener('click', function () {});

            $.ajax({               
                type: 'POST',
                url:  'regist.php',
                data: {del_elem: i},
                success: function( response ){
                    console.log(i);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: А вам точно tr получать нужно? И что выводит в консоль?

Comment: Упс, не тот код отправил, AJAX надо вытянуть из блока `forEach`. Да, TR, при нажатии  ряд удалить.

Comment: ` trash.removeChild ( this )                            `
Вот этот код удаляет ряд, но в AJAX не читает

Comment: Так вы хотите, чтоб ajax читал i за пределами цикла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так. Вместо `console.log` ваш ajax. С помощью `$('#trash td').on('click', function(e){})` мы вешаем слушатель события на все элементы td таблицы, при клике берём значение data-атрибута "label" и работаем с ним. И текущий tr удаляем с помощью `$(this).parent('tr').remove();`

```js
$('#trash td').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let id = $(this).data('label');
  console.log(id);
  $(this).parent('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" >
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>ID R</th><th>ID U</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='trash'>
     <tr>
         <td data-label='ID R'>$row[0]</td>
         <td data-label='ID U'>$row[1]</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, но я забыл уточнить, что только при нажатии на `ID U` или (какой то определенный `TD` ) можно  удалять label, другие игнорируются.

Comment: Можете вешать событие на конкретный td. Если вам помог ответ, отметьте его решением

Comment: Ваш ответ помог, потом делаю проверку `if (e.target.nodeName != 'IMG') {  return false; } else { /***/ }`  и теперь удаляю только при нажатии на нее

Answer (score 0):

```
var WhatWeNeed = $(this).attr('data-label');
```

Comment: И как работать с этим? Что это я вполне догадываюсь, но объясните пожалуйста.